# How to convert dates properly

Tags: r, date

I have several dateformats and need to make them comparable

```
 31.03.2014 00:00 # day, month, year, time
 201410 # year, month
 07.10.2014 # day, month, year
```

How would I convert them to date that they are comparable? I want to perform >, <, = operations as well as calculate days inbetween two dates.

Comment: @etienne I converted `31.03.2014 00:00` and `07.10.2014` with `as.Date(, "%d.%m.%Y)` but that gave me wrong results.

Comment: `as.Date(c('31.03.2014 00:00', '07.10.2014'), '%d.%m.%Y')` works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
input <- c("31.03.2014 10:00", "201410", "07.10.2014")
x <- parse_date_time(input, orders = c("dmY HM", "dmY", "Ym"))
x[1] < x[2]
diff(x)
x + dseconds(1234)
```

Comment: can i do calculations with that?!

Comment: Whats that `POSIXct` format that it gets converted into`

Comment: See `?POSIXct`. It one of the Date-Time classes in R.